# How do you receive the freedom from the Son of God?

Tags: john

Jesus says that He was the only person to set us free. How do we understand and receive freedom?

> John 8:31, 32 - So He said to the Jews who had believed Him, “If you
> continue in My word, you are truly My disciples. 32Then you will know
> the truth, and the truth will set you free.”
>
> John 8:36 - So if the Son sets you free, you will be free indeed.

Comment: welcome to the group Nimral. This site usually requires a specific scripture to deal with.. please give us a chapter and verse.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be received as a gift, given from Christ who is now in heaven, to those people who have put all their faith in what he did to set them free.  It is freedom in Christ that the New Testament speaks of. It is not the sort of freedom from bondage to Egyptian over-lords that the new nation of Israel experienced after God sent ten plagues. They were literally set free, but freedom in Christ means knowing his spiritual freedom even if you were locked up as a persecuted Christian.

The two sets of verses in John chapter 8 that are quoted in the question provide the answer to the question. There's nothing complicated or hidden or esoteric about those verses.

A person believes in Jesus. Of course, that has to be the Jesus of the Bible and not one presented to us from other sources. That person remains in (continues in) Christ's words (which are recorded in the Bible.) That is the hallmark of disciples (followers) of Jesus. They know the 'voice' of their Good Shepherd, as a reading of Jesus' words here proves:

> "But ye believe not because ye are not of my sheep, as I said unto
> you. My sheep hear my voice, and I know them, and they follow me. And
> I give unto them eternal life; and they shall never perish, neither
> shall any man pluck them out of my hand. My Father, which gave them
> me, is greater than all; and no man is able to pluck them out of my
> Father's hand. I and my Father are one." John 10:26-30 A.V.

That is when the believing, obedient person who has faith in Jesus experiences the freedom that only Christ can give. The sense of liberation from sin's enslaving bondage, and alienation from God, has to be experienced to be believed. It is out of this world, because it comes from above. It is spiritual. It gives life to the soul and joy to the heart and peace to the mind. And the security of the believer is assured by the promise of Jesus above. Believing Jesus' promises is part of putting faith in him and experiencing his heavenly freedom.

This is all received by faith (believing trust). It is not received by reciting a creed, or by striving to keep all of the Ten Commandments, or by regularly going to church services, or by doing anything. The person turns in faith to the Son of God, and genuine believers experience transforming grace that liberates them from the bondage they were in prior to proclaiming Christ as their living Lord and Saviour. From then on, they follow Jesus, and no other. I cannot put it any more simply. Going on will unnecessarily complicate matters.

Answer (score 1):

In Romans chapter 16, Paul uses the metaphor of slavery to described those who have lost their freedom. Just as slaves have masters who govern their lives, these individuals would find themselves bound by circumstances beyond their control.

> 16 Don’t you know that when you offer yourselves to someone as obedient slaves, you are slaves of the one you obey—whether you are **slaves to sin**, which leads to death, or to obedience, which leads to righteousness? 17 But thanks be to God that, though you used to be slaves to sin, you have come to obey from your heart the pattern of teaching that has now claimed your allegiance. 18 You have been **set free from sin** and have become **slaves to righteousness.** (NIV)

The phrases "Slaves to sin" and "Slaves to righteousness" can be challenging to grasp. When someone is "set free from sin", how would they become slaves of another?

True freedom isn't merely about doing whatever we please; it's the ability to make deliberate choices. "Slaves to sin" refers to those who have lost the ability to resist sinful impulses. On the other hand, "Slaves to righteousness" represent those who recognize sin and intentional choose to avoid it. Therefore Jesus said in John 8:31-32;

> 31 To the Jews **who had believed him**, Jesus said, “If you hold to my teaching, you are really my disciples. 32 **Then you will know the truth, and the truth will set you free.**” (NIV)

A genuine disciple of Jesus not only knows the truth, but also experiences restoration in their ability to resist sin, ultimately reclaiming their freedom.

Answer (score 0):

**Let Freedom Ring!** The amazing Good News (Gospel) of Christianity is the joyous freedom that comes from being a disciple of Jesus Christ. This **freedom** is diverse and practical for everyday living.

- Freedom from Guilt (Romans 5:17-21)
- Freedom from fear of death
- Freedom from the power of sin (Romans 16:16)
- Freedom from anxiety about provision (Matthew 6 ;25-34)
- Freedom from concern about heaven, after-life (John 14:1-4, 18)
- Freedom from concern about persecution/life's troubles (John16:1-4)
- Freedom from loneliness (1 Corinthians 12:12)
- Freedom from religious Legalism (Galatians 3)
- Freedom from doubt about the Savior (Hebrews 2:1-4)
- Freedom from ignorance and error (John 8:32)

**How  are these possible?** The answer is in the proceeding verse: *Continue in His (Jesus's) Word (teaching), and follow Him as a disciple*. (John 8:31)  Hang on His every word! Drink deeply from the well of Jesus's river of life. "Pick His brain" to get understanding, knowledge, and wisdom. Fulfil the rigors of being a disciple. This means being humble to receive correction, as well, just as a teacher would do for a student. Follow the Master teacher, and along the way, you may enjoy green pastures and still waters to sooth the over-worked mind.

As a disciple you are following in the footsteps of a Master Teacher who has overcome all powers of darkness and doubt, and who is free from all that would enslave Him.  He knows what total freedom is. And He will teach you as well!